# Increase heap size in Kepler Eclipse more than 4GB

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

I have done changes in eclipse.ini file for this -Xmx2048m
but when I have started eclipse again than not able to start.
I have 8GB Ram and 8 Processors, I have using jre 7 64 bit in eclipse.

Comment: what is the error after restart?

Comment: failed to create the java virtual machine

Comment: Please, show version.ini and result of run java -version

Comment: -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx2048m

Comment: java version is  jdk1.7.0_60

Comment: That is a 32 bit Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks   Alexander Fedyukov its works I have 64 bit eclipse. Now I am able to increase heap size till 4GB

Answer (score 1):

It's look like you are working with 32-bit version of Eclipse and\or 32-bit version of java. To solve problem try to install properly x86_64 (64-bit) version of Eclipse and java. Be sure that after installation 64-bit java version was a default.

Comment: Thanks Alexander Fedyukov its works I have 64 bit eclipse. Now I am able to increase heap size till 4GB

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in eclipse.ini file, if you are having the 64 bit eclipse installed

```
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```